# removing multiples in a kernel call for better performance

Tags: c++, cuda, kernel

i'm supposed to remove multiples from this sieve code which is in the kernel call but i don't know if i'm doing it correct or not. every time i enter a value bigger than 20000000, it gives me  this error

```
Prime Sieve v1.0 [CUDA]
computing prime numbers up to but not including 20000000 
========= Program hit error 9 on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so [0x2eeda3]
=========     Host Frame:./sieve_cuda [0x3b27e]
 =========     Host Frame:./sieve_cuda [0x2e34]
 =========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfd) 
[0x1ed1d]
=========     Host Frame:./sieve_cuda [0x2639]
```

this is my code for that kernel call.

```
static __global__ void SieveComputeKernel(const long top, bool array[])
{
  const int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  if ((idx >= 2) && (idx * idx < top))
     {
           int j = idx * idx;
           while (j < top)
            {
            array[j] = false;
            j += idx;
      }


  }
   // ... //todo: remove multiples here

}
```

and this is my kernel call:

```
    SieveComputeKernel<<<(sqrt_top + ThreadsPerBlock - 1) / ThreadsPerBlock, 
    ThreadsPerBlock>>>(top, array_d);
```

where ThreadsPerBlock is 256 and top is that number "2000000"

can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Error 9 on the launch is invalid launch configuration.  At a value of 20000000, your first kernel launch parameter is 20000000/256 which is 78125, and is greater than 65535,  the limit for a cc2.0 device.  If you are using a cc3.0 or higher device, then compile for the compute capability of your device, and you may be able to get past this issue.

Comment: yep that was it

Answer (score 1):

Error 9 on the launch is invalid launch configuration. (You can discover this in [the runtime API documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g3f51e3575c2178246db0a94a430e0038) or else in the header file `driver_types.h`).

At a value of 20000000, your first kernel launch parameter is 20000000/256 which is 78125, and is greater than 65535, the limit for a cc2.0 device.

If you are using a cc3.0 or higher device, then compile for the compute capability of your device (e.g. `nvcc -arch=sm_30 ...`), and you may be able to get past this issue.  (This was evidently the case, based on the comments.)